# What is the most comprehensive way to set an attribute on a model in a has_many association using an attribute of the model it belongs_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activemodel

I have two ActiveModels, `MultivariateExperiment` which `has_many` `MultivariateExperimentVariant`. Conversely, a `MultivariantExperimentVariant` `belongs_to` a `MultivariateExperiment`.

`MultivariateExperiment` has an attribute `experiment_name`.

`MultivariantExperimentVariant` has the attributes `name` and `weighting`.

I'd like the variants' `name` to be in the format `experiment_name_0`, `experiment_name_1`, etc.
For instance, given the following MultivariateExperiment:

```rb
mve = MultivariateExperiment.create({ experiment_name: 'user_signup' })
```

I'd like to have a programmatic way of having the associated variants be:

```rb
mve.multivariate_experiment_variants.create({ weighting: 1 }) # expected name: "user_signup_0"

mve.multivariate_experiment_variants.create({ weighting: 1 }) # expected name: "user_signup_1"

mve.multivariate_experiment_variants.create({ weighting: 2 }) # expected name: "user_signup_2"
```

I initially thought about putting this in an `after_commit` callback but was told in code review to avoid it as that callback is finnicky (not sure why)

I took a look at some other callbacks but none of them seem comprehensive enough to cover the myriad of ways an association can be created, such as the following:

```rb
# 1st approach
mve.multivariate_experiment_variants.create({ weighting: 1 })

# 2nd approach
variant = MultivariateExperimentVariant.create({ weighting: 1 })
mve << variant
mve.save

# 3rd approach
mve.multivariate_experiment_variants.build({ weighting: 1 })
mve.save


# etc. etc.
```

So, given the various ways to create associations, are there any mechanisms or approaches that can successfully compute an attribute of a Model in a `has_many` relationship using an attribute of the Model it belongs to?

Comment: Initial thought is that you can use a virtual attribute instead of storing the variant's name in the database. You not only have to worry about the initial creation (association) of the variant, but also what happens if you update the `MultivariateExperiment` name...you would then have to update all existing associations. Thinking virtual attribute takes care of that...unless you have a need for it to be in the DB

Comment: That's a good thought. I'm a little less worried about the experiment_name changing since it's pretty ingrained in our data team to never alter the parent experiment once created. I think, though, we'd have to have the variant names stored in the database so that it's queryable later on by our data team

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `MultivariateExperimentVariant` model you could do...

```
after_save :set_name

private

def set_name
  # Assuming you have a required belongs_to
  update(name: "#{multivariate_experiment.name}_#{multivariate_experiment.multivariate_experiment_variants.length - 1}")
end
```

You wouldn't want to use `after_commit` unless you specify the `on:` condition

```
after_commit :set_name, on: [:create, :update]
```

Otherwise, it will try to set name after the record is destroyed.

Side note:
It may be better to check the index instead...

```
 update(name: "#{multivariate_experiment.name}_#{multivariate_experiment.multivariate_experiment_variants.index(self)}")
```